# Which Oracle privilege implicitly grant access to other schemas

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I know `IMP_FULL_DATABASE` can let current schema to access tables from other schema

Is there any other privileges do the same?

Comment: Why?  What problem are you trying to solve?  `select any table` clearly does.  `grant any object privilege` arguably does as well.  But questions that just ask for lists of possibilities aren't generally good fits for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grant tables from one schema to other, you have to develop the script:

> Login as schema from which you want to grant

```
begin
  for i in (select * from user_tables)
  loop
    execute immediate 'grant select, insert, update, delete on ' || i.table_name || ' to <target_schema>';
  end loop;
end;
/
```

> `<target_schema>` is the target user to which grants have to be given. Above script grants select, insert, update, delete on all tables from the schema you logged in to `<target_schema>`. Replace `<target_schema>` with the schema name you want to grant to.